# Does FB IOS SDK provide a method to check for the validity of accesstoken?

Tags: ios, facebook

I need to check validity of facebook auth token when my app becomes active.

Auth token might become invalid before the expiry timestamp due to the following reasons

- user changes account password
- user unauthorizes the app

does Facebook IOS SDK provides any method to handle this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes. when any API action goes to exception, you know for sure that you have wrong access token :)

Comment: should you check specifically for FBErrorCategoryAuthenticationReopenSession? I have some questions on this, would you PM me?